# Twitter4j Stream to get own profile tweets

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to use the twitter4j api to **retrieve my own tweets only** (ie, every 3 sec). After using the manual "ResponseList statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();" , i encountered a problem which the request rate was capped.

The solution i can find is to use stream service.
Right now, my stream does not do anything even i update my twitter post.

EDIT 1:

I am able to get it work with my own search criteria. But i am unable to stream once my tweet is private and it works by hashtag search criterion. Any suggestions? I would like to p**rotect my tweets yet able to see my own twitter post stream only.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an [UserStream](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/stream/PrintUserStream.java) and you'll get the tweets as seen by the profile you made the TwitterApp. It'll return private tweets, I just checked (:

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a lifesaver Fean! Been stuck with fabric,twitter and twitter4j for the past 3 days!